# Passing arguments to an environment in Lyx modules?

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts

I have created a LyX module which generates an environment but has one necessary parameter
    Format 66

```
Style Goals
  Category            "Goal Box"
  LatexName           "goalbox"
  LatexType           Environment

  LabelType Above
  Margin Static
  LabelString "Goals of current chapter:"
  LabelFont
    Color blue
    Series bold
  EndFont

  AutoNests
    Itemize, Enumerate, Description     
  EndAutoNests

  Preamble
    \theoremstyle{ocrenumbox}
    \newtheorem*{goalboxT}{Goals of Chapter~\thechapter}
    \newenvironment{goalbox}[1][\unskip]{\begin{goalboxT}[#1]\begin{eBox}\ \begin{enumerate}}{\end{enumerate}\end{eBox}\end{goalboxT}}
  EndPreamble
 End

 ModifyStyle Goals
  Argument 1
    LabelString   "Big goal"
    Tooltip       "No-Optional Big Goal"
  EndArgument
 End
```

which allows me to do

[image: Document screen shot]

which is great. But it shows on screen the somewhat less pleasant variant

[image: LyX Screenshot 1]

but I would like it to show it like

[image: LyX Screenshot 2]

by adding (?)

```
  KeepEmpty 1
  Argument 1
    LabelString " "
    MenuString "Overarching Goal"
    Tooltip "Specify the big picture goal"
    Mandatory 1
    Decoration conglomerate
    AutoInsert 1
  EndArgument
```

but that requires changing to

```
LabelType Static
Margin Dynamic
```

which yields the wrong margins in LyX on screen

[image]

and ignore the argument to the environment the

[image]

Does any of you know how to fix these issue? Specifically:

1. How do I make sure that this argument gets passed along to LaTeX?
2. How can I align all following lines on screen in LyX such that it looks like in the first screenshot?

If this forum is not right for such questions, which is?

Comment: This forum is acceptable to ask any LyX question here (see, e.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). However, there are only a few experienced users answering LyX questions here. If you don't get help, I suggest you send an email to the lyx-users email list. As always, you should cross-reference your questions if you post in multiple places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem can be fixed by

```
Mandatory   0
```

instead of 1 and the second problem by

```
Margin      First_Dynamic
```

Thanks for all help.